# How to run Django's test database only in memory?

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing

My Django unit tests take a long time to run, so I'm looking for ways to speed that up. I'm considering installing an [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), but I know that has its downsides too. Of course, there are things I could do with my code, but I'm looking for a structural fix. Even running a single test is slow since the database needs to be rebuilt / south migrated every time. So here's my idea...

Since I know the test database will always be quite small, why can't I just configure the system to always keep the entire test database in RAM? Never touch the disk at all. How do I configure this in Django?  I'd prefer to keep using [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) since that's what I use in production, but if [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3 or something else makes this easy, I'd go that way.

Does SQLite or MySQL have an option to run entirely in memory? It should be possible to configure a RAM disk and then configure the test database to store its data there, but I'm not sure how to tell Django / MySQL to use a different data directory for a certain database, especially since it keeps getting erased and recreated each run. (I'm on a Mac FWIW.)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

If you set your database engine to sqlite3 when you run your tests, [Django will use a in-memory database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#s-std:setting-TEST_NAME).

I'm using code like this in my `settings.py` to set the engine to sqlite when running my tests:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
```

Or in Django 1.2:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'sqlite3'}
```

And finally in Django 1.3 and 1.4:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
```

(The full path to the backend isn't strictly necessary with Django 1.3, but makes the setting forward compatible.)

You can also add the following line, in case you are having problems with South migrations:

```
    SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

Comment: Do you put that in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I should have put that in my answer! Combine that with SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False and your tests should be a lot faster.

Comment: Awesome!  With these two changes the overhead for running a single fast test in my system has gone from 12 seconds down to <100ms.

Comment: this *is* awesome. on newer django setups use this line: 'ENGINE': 'sqlite3' if 'test' in sys.argv else 'django.db.backends.mysql',

Comment: -1, because testing on different database than the production one is pointless, especially if it's as limited database as SQLite.

Comment: @Tomasz Zielinski - Hmm, it depends what you are testing. But I totally agree that, at the end and from time to time, you need to run the tests with your real database (Postgres, MySQL, Oracle...). But running your tests in-memory with sqlite can save you a lot of time.

Comment: @Etienne: Yes, it can save time, but you can also run tests using your primary database copied to ramdisk, it's very easy with MySQL and then it's not much slower than SQLite. SQLite if *very* different from MySQL, so even if all tests pass on it, it doesn't mean at all that they will pass with MySQL.

Comment: With the new Django syntax, that should be:

if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    
Great solution!

Comment: Isn't Django supposed to be database-agnostic? It *should* function pretty much the same with every DB, right?

Comment: Also, does this really turn on in-memory engine? If it does that automatically, what would you need to do to force sqlite to use flat-file engine instead?

Comment: If I'm right, if you specified a TEST_NAME in the settings, SQLite will use a flat-file. For your first question, has you write, it should function pretty much the same, but it will not necessarily function exactly the same. That's why you really need to run your tests, at least one time, on the DB engine you're using in production before pushing your code to production.

Comment: @Etienne: Ah, you are correct. When running Django (`runserver`), Django will make sqlite use flat-file DB but when running tests and without `TEST_NAME` it will use in-memory DB instead (not flat-file, as I presumed). Thanks for pointing that out. You might want to add note to your answer about that (leaving `TEST_NAME` as `None` or specifying as `:memory:` results in in-memory DB, anything else results in flat-file DB). Otherwise, someone might use sqlite engine but have `TEST_NAME` set to something, and wonder why flat-file is used instead.

Comment: I reverse -1 to +1: as I see it now, it's much faster to use sqlite for quick runs and switch to MySQL for e.g. final daily tests. (Note that I had to do a dummy edit to unlock voting)

Comment: Please note that in-memory SQLite3 DBs do not support access from multiple threads, at least in my setup!  I just ran into this issue and had to switch back to MySQL... :-(

Comment: With Django 1.4 you need to specify the full backend name: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'.

Comment: Quick note; you can use SQLite for running tests locally and then use your production DB engine (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc...) for testing if you have a continuous integration server.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Django>=1.5. It now complains about the NAME field being missing.

Comment: Caution with this `"test" in sys.argv`; it may trigger when you don't want it to, e.g. `manage.py collectstatic -i test`. `sys.argv[1] == "test"` is a more precise condition that should not have that problem.

Comment: This approach seems like it could easily lead to some "gotcha!" situations. It might get the job done, but having a separate settings file is more robust and explicit about what's happening. See Anurag Uniyual's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11018426/1752050

Comment: @doctaphred: I totally agree with you. You know, this answer is now 6 years old!

Answer (score 86):

I usually create a separate settings file for tests and use it in test command e.g.

```
python manage.py test --settings=mysite.test_settings myapp
```

It has two benefits:

1. You don't have to check for `test` or any such magic word in sys.argv, `test_settings.py` can simply be

   ```
   from settings import *

   # make tests faster
   SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
   DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
   ```

   Or you can further tweak it for your needs, cleanly separating test settings from production settings.
2. Another benefit is that you can run test with production database engine instead of sqlite3 avoiding subtle bugs, so while developing use

   ```
   python manage.py test --settings=mysite.test_settings myapp
   ```

   and before committing code run once

   ```
   python manage.py test myapp
   ```

   just to be sure that all test are really passing.

Comment: I like this approach. I have a bunch of different settings files and use them for different server environments but I had not thought about using this method to choose a different test database. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Hi Anurag, I tried this but my other databases mentioned in the settings are also executed. I am not able to figure out the exact reason.

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder how to specify a settings file when running tests through coverage.

Comment: It's a good approach, but not DRY.  Django already knows that you're running tests.  If you could 'hook into' this knowledge somehow, you'd be set.  Unfortunately, I believe that requires extending the management command.  It would probably make sense to make this generic in the core of the framework, by, for example having a setting MANAGEMENT_COMMAND set to the current command whenever manage.py is called, or something to that effect.

Comment: @DylanYoung you can make it dry by including main settings into test_settings and just overriding things you want for test.

Comment: You misunderstand my point.  It's not DRY because of the argv test: Django already knows which command you're running.

Comment: @DylanYoung that is easy, you can write a custom command, you can even override the 'test' command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/  but that doesn't add much , at-least in my case I wanted to optionally pass different settings not always.

Comment: Yes I know. That's what I said: "Unfortunately, I believe that requires extending the management command.". A shell alias would be easier, but less portable :)

Comment: `before committing code run once "python manage.py test myapp"`. I think this should be automated such as using CI or git commit hook. Because people are "lazy", they are not willing to run slow tests while there are quick tests or they will always forget to change the command of different settings.

Answer (score 21):

MySQL supports a storage engine called "MEMORY", which you can configure in your database config (`settings.py`) as such:

```
    'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'OPTIONS': {
        "init_command": "SET storage_engine=MEMORY",
    }
```

Note that the MEMORY storage engine doesn't support blob / text columns, so if you're using `django.db.models.TextField` this won't work for you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning lack of support for blob/text columns. It also doesn't seem to support transactions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Comment: If you really want in-memory tests, you're probably better off going with sqlite which at least supports transactions.

Answer (score 14):

I can't answer your main question, but there are a couple of things that you can do to speed things up.

Firstly, make sure that your MySQL database is set up to use InnoDB. Then it can use transactions to rollback the state of the db before each test, which in my experience has led to a massive speed-up. You can pass a database init command in your settings.py (Django 1.2 syntax):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST':'localhost',
            'NAME':'mydb',
            'USER':'whoever',
            'PASSWORD':'whatever',
            'OPTIONS':{"init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB" } 
        }
    }
```

Secondly, you don't need to run the South migrations each time. Set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` in your settings.py and the database will be created with plain syncdb, which will be much quicker than running through all the historic migrations.

Comment: Great tip! It reduced my tests from `369 tests in 498.704s` to `369 tests in 41.334s `. This is more than 10 times faster!

Comment: Is there an equivalent switch in settings.py for migrations in Django 1.7+ ?

Comment: @EdwardNewell Not exactly.  But you can use `--keep` to persist the database and not require your complete set of migrations to be reapplied on every test run. New migrations will still run. If you're switching between branches frequently, it's easy to get into an inconsistent state though (you can revert new migrations before you switch by changing the database to the test database and running `migrate`, but it's a bit of a pain).

Answer (score 10):

You can do double tweaking:

- use transactional tables: initial fixtures state will be set using database rollback after every TestCase.
- put your database data dir on ramdisk: you will gain much as far as database creation is concerned and also running test will be faster.

I'm using both tricks and I'm quite happy.

How to set up it for MySQL on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo cp -pRL /var/lib/mysql /dev/shm/mysql

$ vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# datadir = /dev/shm/mysql
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Beware, it's just for testing, after reboot your database from memory is lost!

Comment: thanks! works for me. I can't use sqlite, because I'm using features specific to mysql (full-text indexes).

For ubuntu users, you'll have to edit your apparmor config to allow mysqld access to /dev/shm/mysql

Comment: Cheers for the heads up Ivan and Potr. Disabled the AppArmor mysql profile for now, but found a guide for customising the relevant local profile: https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql

Comment: Hmm. I've tried customising the local profile to give mysqld access to the /dev/shm/mysql path and its contents, but the service can only start in 'complain' mode (aa-complain command) and not 'enforce', for some reason... A question for another forum! What I can't understand is how there are no 'complaints' at all when it does work, implying that mysqld isn't violating the profile...

Answer (score 4):

Another approach: have another instance of MySQL running in a tempfs that uses a RAM Disk. Instructions in this blog post: [*Speeding up MySQL for testing in Django*](http://andrefsp.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/speeding-up-mysql-django-testing/).

Advantages:

- You use the exactly same database that your production server uses
- no need to change your default mysql configuration

Answer (score 2):

Extending on Anurag's answer I simplified the process by creating the same test_settings and adding the following to manage.py

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "test":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.test_settings")
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

seems cleaner since sys is already imported and manage.py is only used via command line, so no need to clutter up settings

Comment: How does this let you ever run against your production db?

Comment: would need to be extended to so -- or you could set the settings file manually via the command line -- question of which you test on more often

Comment: I like this approach, but to be clear, will passing --settings=mysite.settings use settings and not test_settings?

Comment: Caution with this `"test" in sys.argv`; it may trigger when you don't want it to, e.g. `manage.py collectstatic -i test`. `sys.argv[1] == "test"` is a more precise condition that should not have that problem.

Comment: @keturn this way it generates an exception when running `./manage.py` without arguments (eg to see which plugins are available, same as `--help`)

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins That's trivial to resolve: `len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "test"`

Comment: @DylanYoung Yes, that's exactly what I wanted Alvin to add to his solution but he isn't particularly interested in improving it. Anyway it looks more like a quick hack than the legit solution.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins It is a bit hacky, but as long as you have a standard testing process (that involves `test` as the first arg) it should work fine.  A clean solution implementing the same general principle, would be to extend the Django test management command and set a variable there.

Comment: haven't looked at this answer in a while, I updated the snippet to reflect @DylanYoung's improvement

Comment: @DylanYoung Actually it could be written even more hacky (although less readable): `if sys.argv[1:2] == ['test']:` but as a reader I'd prefer the more verbose variant :)

Answer (score -1):

Use below in your `setting.py`

```
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
```