# Django unit test without creating test database every time I run

Tags: django, unit-testing

Seems like "manage.py test" creates test database every time I run the test. Is there a way to prevent creating test database each time I run test but just truncate data (flush)?

My tables are almost about 40 tables (even for single app, not the whole project), and makes me sick every time I run test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on your needs you have a few choices:

- You could write a custom test runner or adjust the default one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/advanced/#other-testing-frameworks
- You could use [SimpleTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase)
- There are also add-ons like [django-test-utils](http://django-test-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/keep_database_runner.html) (although I'm not sure if that specific one works with modern Django versions).
- Alternatively, to speed everything up, you could use [SQLite's in-memory database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) OR create your [test database in RAM disk (like tmpfs or ramfs)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4437821/176186) - in fact this is orthogonal to using other techniques.

Answer (score 37):

From Django 1.8 on you could use the --keepdb flag, when calling the manage.py

> New in Django 1.8: You can prevent the test databases from being
>   destroyed by adding the **--keepdb flag** to the test command. This will
>   preserve the test database between runs. If the database does not
>   exist, it will first be created. Any migrations will also be applied
>   in order to keep it up to date.
>   (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

So your call could look as follows:

```
python manage.py test --keepdb
```

Or using the shorthand -k it could look like that:

```
python manage.py test -k
```

Comment: For modern Django (1.8 or higher) with default test kit - that's the easiest.

Comment: Even with keepdb, django insists on running migrations every time

Comment: @Matt _If the test database
does not exist, it will be created on the first run and then preserved for each
subsequent run. Any unapplied migrations will also be applied to the test
database before running the test suite._ [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb)

Comment: @Matt But yes, the migrations will be applied every time you run the tests (see the [django-source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/creation.py#L63L69) for reference). However, running the tests with a higher verbosity mode (`python manage.py test -k --verbosity 2`), you will see the migrations are only checked, but not reapplied if they have been applied before and were not changed in between test runs.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe can try with [test runner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/advanced/)

Example:

First, create `test_runners.py`

```py
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class NoDbTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        """ Override the database creation defined in parent class """
        pass

    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        """ Override the database teardown defined in parent class """
        pass
```

Then declare above runner in `settings.py`

```py
TEST_RUNNER = 'api.tests.test_runners.NoDbTestRunner'
```

Answer (score 1):

django-nose supports reusing the database:

https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose#enabling-database-reuse

However, make sure to read the comments:

> The one new wrinkle is that, whenever your DB schema changes, you
>   should leave the flag off the next time you run tests. This will cue
>   the test runner to reinitialize the test database.
>
> Also, REUSE_DB is not compatible with TransactionTestCases that leave
>   junk in the DB, so be sure to make your TransactionTestCases hygienic
>   (see below) if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will also reduce the db creation time if there are more number of south migrations. During unit testing, running syncdb instead of running all the south migrations will be much faster.

> SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False # To disable migrations and use syncdb
>   instead

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is not best practice, but something that I have done as a workaround is to create a few different test programs in the management/commands directory within the app.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/

For example, I'm working on an app now that requires some advanced Postgres functionality (cannot use Sqlite) so instead of creating test functions as part of tests.py, I created test_process.py in myapp/management/commands/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have `pytest` as test runner. Configuration example follows.

Sample `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
norecursedirs=
    *.egg
    .git
    .tox
    .env
    _sass
    build
    dist
    migrations
    fabfile
    .tox
python_files =
    test_*.py
    tests.py
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.dev
addopts=
   --reuse-db
   --nomigrations
   --cov=your_app
   --ignore=.tox
   --ignore=fabfile
   --ignore=scripts
   --ignore=settings
   --ignore=tmp
   --cov-report=html
   --cov-report=term
   --cov-report=annotate
```

Sample `runtests.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

import pytest


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.dev")
    return pytest.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Sample `requirements.txt` file:

```
pytest==3.0.2
pytest-django==2.9.1
pytest-cov==2.2.1
```

Run the tests:

```
./runtests.py
```

Note, that effect is achieved through `reuse-db` and `nomigrations` directives.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Django have a --keepdb argument you can pass to tests so the database doesn't get destroyed and rebuilt on each run.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb