# difference between django.test.TestCase vs unittest vs django.utils.unittest.TestCase

Tags: django, django-testing

I am still using Django 1.2.1, and I think with the newer Django we don't `import unittest` and then do `unittest.TestCase`.

**Illustration**

```
import unittest
class TestThis(unittest.TestCase):

from django.utils.unittest import TestCase
class TestThis(TestCase):

from django.test import TestCase
class TestThis(TestCase):
```

According to [PyCon2011 talk](http://pycon-2012-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_and_django.html), the second one is **slightly** more efficient.

Here is the [diagram](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#testcase) showing the relations:

[image]

So `django.utils.unittest` and `django.test` inherit from either `unittest` or `unittest2`.

I am not sure if the following is correct or not. Please help editing.

```
 ________________________________________________________________
|  Name                   |  Django Version  |  Python Version  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  unittest               |     >= 1.0       |      >= 2.6      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  django.utils.unittest  |     >= 1.3       |       ??         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  django.test            |     >= 1.0       |      >= 2.6      |
|   - SimpleTestCase            >= 1.4              >= 2.7      |
|   - LiveServerTestCase        >= 1.4              >= 2.7      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In terms of efficiency, which one of the three is better? Many Django developers mock when they test, so sometimes database are not even necessary. Is there a way not creating tables when we run `manage.py test myapp.MyClass` ? For older version (prior to 1.3), which one is better?

Answer (score 20):

Django's `TestCase` enhances `unittest.TestCase` with some extra features:

- Automatic loading of fixtures.
- Wraps each test in a transaction.
- Creates a TestClient instance.
- Django-specific assertions for testing for things like redirection and form errors.

Generally speaking, you should most likely be using one of Django's TestCase subclasses. Usually this will be `django.test.TestCase`, which, for efficiency, wraps the test in a DB transaction and uses rollback to 'undo' the test in the DB. If you need to manually manage transactions within your test, you would need to use `django.test.TransactionTestCase`, since you can't start / rollback a transaction within a transaction.

There are some minor caveats to using `django.test.TestCase`, see the note [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase) for more information.

ALSO:

If you're just looking for a way to run your tests faster, have a look at [running your tests in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096148/how-to-run-djangos-test-database-only-in-memory), and (if you're using South), set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` to tell South to use a (much faster) `syncdb` when creating the test DB, rather than running migrations.

Comment: I created a django app, and i have in my test.py file, an example class inheriting from *TestCase* and I have only imported the *TestCase* from *django.test*. If I import *unittest.TestCase*, would it be a conflict?

Comment: @eLRuLL yes, but you could do "from django.test import TestCase as DjangoTestCase" or something similar to resolve the conflict

Comment: The link for caveats to using `django.test.TestCase` is 404ing