# django unittest throws exceptions

Tags: python, django

I have a problem. When I create very simple test in Django I have exceptions like this:

```
import unittest 
from django.test import Client

class ModelTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_basic(self):
        response = self.client.get('/login/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The error I get is:

```
FAILED (errors=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ateris\portal\module\RiskCard\tests\test_models.py", line 11, in test_basic
response = self.client.get('/login/')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 500, in get
**extra)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 303, in get
return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 358, in generic
data = force_bytes(data, settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_CHARSET, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I use the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) documentation.

I am using PyCharm

Python ver: **2.7.12**

Django ver: **1.8.5**

Comment: Have you read the error message? And updated things accordingly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django DB Settings 'Improperly Configured' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556499/django-db-settings-improperly-configured-error)

Comment: Exactly what did you type to run the tests?

Comment: @DanielRoseman just 'Run' in PyCharm

Comment: Well, that won't work. Either use the specific PyCharm support for Django (which I think is in the enterprise edition only) or run them from the shell via `manage.py test`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you, I use the shell and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Client

class UserTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        test_client = Client.objects.get(id=[ClientsID])
    def test_basic(self):
        response = self.client.get('/login/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Your wrong part is that you define `self.client = Client()` and then you use `self.client.get('/login/')` while it contains a query.

Comment: What is a difference between import unittest a django.test import TestCase?
The client is not object in my models. I use this to simulate GET and POST requests on a URL and observe the response.

Answer (score 0):

By default `django` `TestCase` inherits the python unit TestCase and extends it's functionality to speedup the process of unit Testing. By default it provides client.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class ModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_basic(self):
        response = self.client.get('/login/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#tests-and-multiple-host-names

Answer (score 0):

Just a little modification, here you go:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class ModelTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_basic(self):
        response = self.client.get('/login/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Everything will work like a charm. In case you are curious to know the differences. Visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064846/difference-between-django-test-testcase-vs-unittest-vs-django-utils-unittest-tes)

Hope that might clear your understanding.