# Using different database with pytest

Tags: python, django, sqlite, testing, pytest

I am using to run tests for my django application pytest with pytest-django plugin. I use MySQL database as a default one for django. Is there possiblity to specify just for pytest to use different database for tests, SQLite?

I am looking for different option if any, than creating special test_seetings.py for py.test --ds=test_settings.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096148/how-to-run-djangos-test-database-only-in-memory)?

Comment: I think that those answers are for running tests trough manage.py. I run tests with py.test command.

Comment: Ah then it doesn't apply to your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`--ds=test_settings` is the way to go!

If you dont want to type out `--ds=...` every time you invoke py.test, you can add a pytest.ini with this contents:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
```

As a side note: It is good practice to use the same type of database that you use in production when running your tests. pytest-django provides the [`--reuse-db`](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database.html) option to re-use a MySQL/Postgres database between test runs, saving a lot of setup time when running a few tests for projects with lots of models.

Comment: Running test on a production database? Do you mean a database reprenting a production like database, or a database which is used in production? I hope not the latter.

Comment: @OrangeTux I definitely agree with you, that sentence is misleading and not what I intended it to be. To clarify, what I meant is that if you use PostgreSQL in production, you should run your test suite against a PostgreSQL database. You should *not* run your tests agains your actual production database with production data. Some people suggest to use SQLite for local development to speed up tests - I think that is an anti-pattern. --reuse-db is the way to go to still have fast tests *and* make sure your system works with the same kind of database you use in production.

Comment: (I can't seem to edit the original answer, if anyone with enough reputation can do that, feel free to rephrase the answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run tests under a "real" database but don't want to use your main database for it because it's too slow, you can use sqlite for the particular test.

```
import tempfile
from django.db import models, connections
from django.db.backends.sqlite3.base import DatabaseWrapper as SqliteConnection


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def sqlite_db(django_db_blocker):
    """
    Runs tests inside a sqlite3, making it slightly faster.
    When using this, avoid using the `@pytest.mark.django_db` and put the name `sqlite_db` as your
    first function parameter.

    Example:

        def test_something(sqlite_db):
            # This test will run inside a unique and isolated sqlite db

            with connection.cursor() as c, connection.schema_editor() as editor:
                editor.create_model(User)  # c.execute('CREATE TABLE ...')
                user = User.objects.create(username='test')  # c.execute('INSERT INTO ...')
                assert user.username == 'test'
                editor.delete_model(User)  # c.execute('DROP TABLE ...')
            
    """
    # Tells pytest-django that it's ok to use the db
    django_db_blocker.unblock()

    # Create a backup of the current db connection
    original_connection = connections['default']

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        db_settings = {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': f.name,
            'TIME_ZONE': None,
            'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
            'OPTIONS': {},
            'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
        }
        # Override the `default` connection with the sqlite one
        connections['default'] = SqliteConnection(db_settings)

        # Call your test
        yield

        # Clean up
        connections['default'].close()
        # Put back the connection
        connections['default'] = original_connection

    # Tell pytest-django to restore the db lock
    django_db_blocker.restore()
```

**Note**: the lack of `@pytest.mark.django_db` decorator on the example test (docstring).

**Note**: this will give you a brand new db with NOTHING inside, you need to create your models and populate it if you want to use it. See `editor = connections['default'].schema_editor(); editor.create_model(User)` and don't forget to clean up after yourself: `editor.delete_model(User)`