# Python - how to run end to end test cases with mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, database, functional-testing

Is there any in memory DB for Python similar to HSQLDB. MySQL is the DB the application uses and for running end to end test cases, we are currently bringing up a clone of actual DB which causes some delay and couple of manual steps.

I have tried SQLite3 facing some trouble with running DDL queries generated for MySQL.

What are the good options for bringing up temporary DB to run all test cases and shut it down after test execution?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096148/how-to-run-djangos-test-database-only-in-memory). It lists several different options in several answers so make sure you check them down the page.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has an in-memory engine (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html). I've never used, but I guess it will help you run the tests quickly.